# ESP32 digital IO output inconsistent voltage

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, esp32, ldr, io

I have a problem which I have been fighting with for several days now. I can't see any possible solution. Maybe someone could give me push in the right direction, that would mean a lot.

I ordered 5 identical assembled PCBs according to my schematic, which I designed on a breadboard and then in KiCad. You can see the relevant part of the schematic below.

I am encountering a problem with the ESP32:

When I drive  **pin 25** (labeled "ldr_en") HIGH, I get inconsistent voltages.

The power supply is stable at 3.3V from a LDO, but the pin is outputting voltages as low as 1.8V when HIGH. I sometimes get up to 2.8V, sometimes 2.5V and sometimes even below 2V (measured with a multimeter) - it seems random.

```
const int ldr_en = 25, ldr = 36;

void setup() {
  pinMode(ldr_en, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ldr, INPUT);

  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(ldr_en, HIGH);

  delay(1500);
  Serial.print("LDR: ");
  Serial.println(analogRead(ldr));

  delay(200);
  digitalWrite(ldr_en, LOW);

  delay(1500);
}
```

Some other randomly tested IOs seem to work fine (3.2-3.3V when HIGH.)

The thing is that the problem exists across the boards. I tested 4 already and 3 of them seem to have this inconsistency.

Attached to the pin is one voltage divider with an LDR and one voltage divider for monitoring battery voltage (see schematic.) The LDR voltage divider has a switch to toggle between an internal LDR and an external LDR. For the tests, only the internal LDR was used (switch in other position than shown).

Because of the inconsistent voltage at the pin 25, I get inconsistent sensor readings at" ldr_val" (pin 36), which makes the circuit unusable.

The two voltage dividers (ldr_en is connected to IO25, ldr is connected to IO36, v_batt is connected to IO39):

[image: the two voltage dividers]

Does someone have an idea where such a problem could come from or if my circuit is somehow faulty?

Maybe I treated the PCBs badly, but I can't figure how.

If you have some more tests I could run, I am happy to do so, to help solve the problem.

Comment: Remove R21 and see if the voltage is correct on pin 25.

Comment: @JRE I do need the base resistor, don't I? Otherwise current flowing through Q5 would be too high?

Comment: I meant "remove R21."  No connection between pin 25 and the transistor.  See if the voltage on pin 25 is OK then.

Comment: I removed the resistor and the problem stayed the same. Also a different problem: It seems that my voltage divider with the LDR puts out unplausible voltages which dont reflect the actual resistance changes. Could there be something wrong with the voltage divider itself? Maybe that causes the voltage drops also?